# How to change the color of the x and y pixels to blue?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.ones((400, 400,3),np.uint8)*255

circle = np.ones((400, 400))*255  
for theta in np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01):
    for r in np.arange(150, 160, 1):
        x = 200 + r * np.cos(theta)
        y = 200 + r * np.sin(theta)

        circle[int(x)][int(y)] = 0
cv2.imshow('c',circle)
```

This gives the output:

[image]

How do I change the colors of those black pixels to blue?
If I do

```
circle[int(x)][int(y)] = (255,0,0)
```

It gives an error saying `"setting an array element with a sequence."`

Answer (score 1):

Your `circle` is not a 3D array but a 2D array (`(400, 400)`) so there is no RGB dimension. Try to make it a 3D array.

```py
circle = np.ones((400, 400, 3))*255
```

And then, you will be able to do

```py
circle[int(x)][int(y)] = [255,0,0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your array is 2D, your colors can only be gray-scale. Too fix it, add another dimension to the shape of the array:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.ones((400, 400, 3), np.uint8) * 255
circle = np.ones((400, 400, 3)) * 255
```

With numpy arrays, you can use a comma for nested slicing:

```
for theta in np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01):
    for r in np.arange(150, 160, 1):
        x = 200 + r * np.cos(theta)
        y = 200 + r * np.sin(theta)
        circle[int(x), int(y)] = 255, 0, 0

cv2.imshow('c',circle)
```

Finally, instead of doing `np.ones((400, 400, 3)) * 255`, you can do `np.full((400, 400, 3), 255)`